# Counting Occurences of a String within elements of a list?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to count the amount of times `"a class"` occurs within each `"h2 class"`, so I split the parsed texted by `"h2 class"` but am having struggles with the second part, this is where I'm at

```
#splitting parsed text by header
parsed.split("h2 class")

#creating the list for the a value count to be stored
aValCount = []

#counting amount of items per header
for i in range (len(parsed)):
    aValCount = aValCount + ((parsed[i]).count("a class"))
```

the error I'm getting is

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

, but I can't figure out how to this without getting some sort of error

Edited: Thought I should add, I want it to be a list of the counts from the strings, so the count from element one in parsed, should be element 1 in `aValCount`

Comment: Initialize `aValCount=0`

Comment: Thought I should add, I want it to be a list of the counts from the strings, so the count from element one in parsed, should be element 1 in aValCount

Comment: I see, you need to use `append()` as the actual answer suggests then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `aValCount` is an array and `((parsed[i]).count("a class"))` is an int.

What you want is to add the count to `aValCount` so you need to pass another array.

`aValCount = aValCount + [((parsed[i]).count("a class"))]`

If you add `[...]` that should do it.
Or you can also do

`aValCount.append(((parsed[i]).count("a class"))])`

Hope that help.

```
results = parsed.split("h2 class")
aValCountList = []

for i in range (len(results)):
    aValCountList.append((results[i]).count("a class"))
```

Comment: When I try to print this, I get a significant amount of zeros, would that be a zero for every occurrence?  I'm trying to have it to be a list of the counts from the strings, so the count from element one in parsed, should be element 1 in aValCount

Comment: You need to assign the value of the split to another variable.